# Jquery fails to match html attribute of long string length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Recently i've been encrypting my primary keys using AES encryption, 128-bit, resulting in values such as

`eyJpdiI6ImRyMXR5QllPVHM5OEJqdFM3azl2SGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC82dVhLQ3pWYnd6QkZZdHZDZlRWSmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjgwNmVlMTI0Y2EzMWVmMGI1NTk1OWM5ZGNkYzA0ZWQwYzMwYjNhYzJmOTg2NjUzOTBjZjQ3MmE3YWUwYzY4ZDEifQ==`

Placing the value in a data attribute, such as the example below, works just fine.

`<a data-pk="eyJpdiI6ImRyMXR5QllPVHM5OEJqdFM3azl2SGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC82dVhLQ3pWYnd6QkZZdHZDZlRWSmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjgwNmVlMTI0Y2EzMWVmMGI1NTk1OWM5ZGNkYzA0ZWQwYzMwYjNhYzJmOTg2NjUzOTBjZjQ3MmE3YWUwYzY4ZDEifQ=="></a>`

However if i attempt to match that `data-pk` attribute in Jquery, see below, **No html element will be returned**.

Any ideas?

`$("a[data-pk='eyJpdiI6ImRyMXR5QllPVHM5OEJqdFM3azl2SGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC82dVhLQ3pWYnd6QkZZdHZDZlRWSmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjgwNmVlMTI0Y2EzMWVmMGI1NTk1OWM5ZGNkYzA0ZWQwYzMwYjNhYzJmOTg2NjUzOTBjZjQ3MmE3YWUwYzY4ZDEifQ==']")`

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8fm1tqma/

There is nothing in the [W3C HTML5 draft](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#custom-data-attribute) concerning limitations in value length for `data-` attributes.

Comment: Get rid of the [0] in your jsfiddle, you want the length of the found elements and you're asking for the length of the first found element.  It then alerts '1' for me

Comment: Indeed it is working now, yet fails to work in my app using jquery 2.1.1

Comment: Don't know the exact reason. But try using `.size()` and see if that works for your app.

Comment: Nevermind; it turns out, the primary key is different for each client, connected to the application. So much for encryption..

Answer (score 0):

Update your code as `$("selector")[0]` returns you the `dom` of element (which is `HTML <a> Tag` in this case) and `dom` doesn't have the property named `length`.That's why you are getting. `undefined`.
Fetch your `data-pk` attribute from `dom` by `dom.getAttribute("attribute-name")` method.

eg:-

```
alert($("a[data-pk='eyJpdiI6ImRyMXR5QllPVHM5OEJqdFM3azl2SGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC82dVhLQ3pWYnd6QkZZdHZDZlRWSmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjgwNmVlMTI0Y2EzMWVmMGI1NTk1OWM5ZGNkYzA0ZWQwYzMwYjNhYzJmOTg2NjUzOTBjZjQ3MmE3YWUwYzY4ZDEifQ==']")[0].getAttribute("data-pk").length);//call getAttribute on dom which returns pk
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/8fm1tqma/5/

Or Simply do it using [$.data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

```
alert($("a").data("pk").length);//length of pk data
```

Here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/8fm1tqma/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text of that particularly matching data-pk value using

```
alert($("a[data-pk='eyJpdiI6ImRyMXR5QllPVHM5OEJqdFM3azl2SGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiXC82dVhLQ3pWYnd6QkZZdHZDZlRWSmc9PSIsIm1hYyI6IjgwNmVlMTI0Y2EzMWVmMGI1NTk1OWM5ZGNkYzA0ZWQwYzMwYjNhYzJmOTg2NjUzOTBjZjQ3MmE3YWUwYzY4ZDEifQ==']").text());
```

And You can find the length of the pk using

```
alert($("a").data('pk').length);
```